# Configuring Static IP Block On Meraki Security Appliance

Tags: cisco, routing, nat, ip

I have two network appliances configured on a network, an older Juniper Firewall and a Meraki Security Appliance.

In the Juniper device I can use the base static IP address, ex: xx.xx.xx.xx and then I can use a /29 prefix and route all of the static IP traffic through said device.

I configure the untrusted uplink as such: xx.xx.xx.xx/29

How do I replicate this on a Meraki or other networking device?

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  You can assign a vlan ip & subnet in meraki and then assign that vlan to a port on the meraki if thats what you are asking?

Comment: Not quite - I have 5 static IP addresses that I'd like to be able to NAT but we have a Comcast gateway/cable modem that is providing the addresses. I've been able to get it roughly working but the NAT's are still not working.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

1:1 NAT (under Configure > Firewall) is the right way to route multiple public IP addresses.  https://kb.meraki.com/knowledge_base/configuring-11-nat